# proper way to use selenium locator on a navigation bar

Tags: html, selenium

I've been spending a lot of time  learning selenium on my own, I have selected a Website "actiTime.com" to practice what I have learnt and as I started automating scripts I came across an issue that has left me stumped for two days. I thought this would be a good place to ask since you guys are an expert on this field.

It is a navigation menu with all the content in a HTML Grid.My query, **is this  approach appropriate to use this locator to extract the names of the menus on the navigation bar**

I'm trying to extract names of the navigation bar which are Time-Track, Task,Reports,User(Which are actually modules of the webapplication)

My code:

```
public class Test50_misc extends Browser{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    call_chrome();<-System property
    WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("https://online.actitime.com/adbc/login.do");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@name='pwd']")).sendKeys("xxxxx");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='loginButton']")).click();
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

    WebElement e=driver.findElement(
    By.xpath(".//table[@class ='navTable']//tr[1]"));//Reducing the scope of driver that particular area

     List<WebElement>all_links=e.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'label')]"));
    for(WebElement element:all_links){
        sb.append(element.getAttribute("innerHTML")).append(" : ");//HOW TO USE STRING BUILDER

    }
    System.out.println(sb);

}
```

}

***Expected output***:-
TIME-TRACK : TASKS : REPORTS : USERS :

**Actual Output** was
TIME-TRACK : TASKS : REPORTS : USERS : 
            Settings
             
         : 
            Add-ons
             
         : 
            Help
             
         : 
            Tips
             : 
            Select customer or project
         :

Which is not what I'm interested in since it is including items of another sub table (Help,Tips..)

Html Dom Structure

```
<div class="navBg withSubMenu">
<table class="navTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="topnav" style="cursor: default;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="logoCell navCell" valign="top">
            <div style="position: relative">
                <div><img src="/adbc/img/ferngreen/pixel.gif?hash=993496393" height="1" width="190"></div>

                    <div style="padding:19px 0 0 28px"><img src="/adbc/img/ferngreen/top_nav/default-logo.png?hash=993496393" height="44" width="145"></div>

            </div>
        </td>          

        <td class="navItem navCell relative selected">    

            <a class="content selected tt">
                <div class="label">TIME-TRACK</div>
                <div class="img">&nbsp;</div>
            </a>                            

        </td>    

        <td class="navItem navCell relative notSelected">

            <a href="/adbc/tasks/otasklist.do" class="content tasks"><div class="label" style="z-index:155; ">TASKS</div>//<----Label
                <div class="img">&nbsp;</div></a>       

        </td>               

        <td class="navItem navCell relative notSelected">    

            <a href="/adbc/reports/reports.do" class="content reports"><div class="label" style="z-index:155; ">REPORTS</div>
                <div class="img">&nbsp;</div></a>

        </td>    

        <td class="navItem navCell relative notSelected">              

            <a href="/adbc/administration/userlist.do" class="content users"><div class="label" style="z-index:155; ">USERS</div>
                <div class="img">&nbsp;</div></a>                        

        </td>               

        <td class="menuCell navCell" valign="top">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td valign="top">

                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <div class="menuCellDiv">
                            <table class="menuTableWrap" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <tbody><tr class="logoutContainer">
                                    <td class="profileCell">
                                        <a class="userProfileLink username" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="onUserProfileLinkClicked(); return false;">
                                            adda

                                            london
                                        </a>

                                    </td>
                                    <td class="logoutSeparator">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td class="logoutCell">
                                        <a href="/adbc/logout.do" id="logoutLink" class="logout">Logout</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                        <div class="menuTable">

                                            <div class="topMenuButton">    


<div class="popup_menu_container">
    <div class="popup_menu_button popup_menu_button_settings" onclick="PopupMenu.show(event, $('#popup_menu_settings'));">
        <div class="popup_menu_icon settings_icon">

        </div>
        <div class="popup_menu_label">
            Settings
            <div class="popup_menu_arrow">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="popup_menu_settings" class="popup_menu_body">
        <div class="popup_beak"></div>
        <div class="popup_menu_content popup_menu_settings">
            <div class="popup_menu_ul">
                <div class="popup_menu_title">
                    SETTINGS
                </div>
                <ul id="popup_menu_items_content" class="popup_menu_items">
                    <li class="popup_menu_separator"></li>

                    <li class="popup_menu_item" id="popup_menu_item_1"><a href="/adbc/administration/features.do" class="item_link"><div class="item_title">Turn Features On / Off</div>
                        <div class="item_descr">Review features and decide what you need</div></a></li>

                    <li class="popup_menu_separator"></li>

                    <li class="popup_menu_item" id="popup_menu_item_6">
                        <a href="/adbc/administration/settings.do?noReload=false" class="item_link"><div class="item_title">

                                General Settings
                            </div>
                            <div class="item_descr">Manage system settings &amp; configure actiTIME</div></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="popup_menu_separator"></li>                            
                    <li class="popup_menu_item" id="popup_menu_item_2" style=" "><a href="/adbc/administration/btlist.do" class="item_link">Types of Work</a></li>                                                   
                    <li class="popup_menu_item" id="popup_menu_item_3" style=" "><a href="/adbc/administration/ltlist.do" class="item_link">Leave ypes</a></li>                       

                    <li class="popup_menu_item" id="popup_menu_item_4"><a href="/adbc/administration/workingdays.do" class="item_link">Work Schedule</a>
```

li>

```
                    <li class="popup_menu_item" id="popup_menu_item_5"><a href="/adbc/administration/notifications.do" class="item_link">Notifications</a></li>                            
                    <li class="popup_menu_separator"></li>    
                    <li class="popup_menu_item" id="popup_menu_item_7"><a href="/adbc/administration/customization.do" class="item_link">Logo &amp; Color Scheme</a></li>    
                    <li class="popup_menu_item" id="popup_menu_item_8"><a href="/adbc/administration/manage_licenses.do" class="item_link">Licenses</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
                                            </div>                                                
                                            <div class="topMenuButton">                                


<div class="popup_menu_container">
    <div class="popup_menu_button popup_menu_button_addons" onclick="PopupMenu.show(event, $('#popup_menu_addons'));">
        <div class="popup_menu_icon addons_icon"></div>
        <div class="popup_menu_label">
            Add-ons
            <div class="popup_menu_arrow">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="popup_menu_addons" class="popup_menu_body">
        <div class="popup_beak"></div>
        <div class="popup_menu_content popup_menu_addons">
            <div class="popup_menu_ul">
                <div class="popup_menu_title">
                    ADD-ONS 
                </div>
                <ul class="popup_menu_items">
                    <li class="popup_menu_separator"></li>
                    <li class="popup_menu_item"><a class="item_link has_icon mobile_icon" href="https://www.actitime.com/actitime-mobile-app.html" target="_blank">
                        <div class="item_title">actiTIME mobile app</div>
                        <div class="item_descr">FREE mobile application for iPhone &amp; Android</div>
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="popup_menu_separator"></li>
                    <li class="popup_menu_item"><a class="item_link has_icon qb_icon" href="https://www.actitime.com/timesheet-quickbooks-integration.html" target="_blank">
                        <div class="item_title">Integration with QuickBooks</div>
                        <div class="item_descr">Import working and leave time into QuickBooks</div>
                    </a></li>
                    <li class="popup_menu_separator"></li>
                    <li class="popup_menu_item">

                            <a class="item_link has_icon actiplans_icon" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openAtIntegrationPopup(); return false;">

                                <div class="item_title">Integration with actiPLANS</div>
                                <div class="item_descr" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">Interactive schedule for planning leaves and checking collegues' presence at work</div>
                            </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="topMenuButton">

<div class="popup_menu_container">
    <div class="popup_menu_button popup_menu_button_support" onclick="openHelpAndSupportMenu(event)">
        <div class="popup_menu_icon support_icon"></div>
        <div class="popup_menu_label">
            Help
            <div class="popup_menu_arrow">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="popup_menu_support" class="popup_menu_body popup_menu_support_container">
        <div class="popup_beak"></div>
        <div class="popup_menu_content popup_menu_support demoDataLoaded inviteUsersPossible">

            <div id="demoDataContainer" class="demoDataContainer">
                <div class="demoDataScrollContainer">
                    <div class="firstTextBlock">
                        <span class="demoDataLoadedTitle">Demo Data Loaded</span>
                        <div class="demoDataLoadedNote">
                            To save your time for the product review we've preloaded sample data (Users, Tasks, etc.).<br><br>
                            You can remove these data anytime when you are ready to start working with product.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cleanDemoDataButton" class="cleanDemoDataButton">Clean up Demo Data</div>
                    <div class="removeDemoDataText">Preloaded Demo Data will be removed from actiTIME. All data created by you (Settings, Customers, Projects, Tasks, Users, etc.) will be kept in the system.</div>
                    <div id="proceedCleanDemoDataButton" class="proceedCleanDemoDataButton">Proceed with Clean up</div>
                    <div id="cancelDemoDataClenup" class="cancelDemoDataClenup">Cancel</div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="inviteUserFromHelpPopup" class="inviteUserFromHelpPopup">
                <div class="scrollInviteContainer">
                    <div class="inviteTeamPicture"><img src="/adbc/img/ferngreen/support/team-pic-demo.png?hash=993496393"></div>
                    <div id="popup_menu_support_createAccountColleague" class="createAccountColleague">Create account for your colleague</div>
                    <div class="inviteInputFieldsContainer">
                        <div style="width: 250px">
                            <input id="popup_menu_support_firstNameInviteMenu" maxlength="32" class="firstNameInviteMenu inputFieldWithPlaceholder" type="text" placeholder="First Name"><!-- this comment is needed to remove space between inputs
                                   --><input id="popup_menu_support_lastNameInviteMenu" maxlength="32" class="lastNameInviteMenu inputFieldWithPlaceholder " type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                        </div>
                        <input id="popup_menu_support_emailInviteMenu" class="emailInviteMenu inputFieldWithPlaceholder" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                        <div>
                            <div id="popup_menu_support_sendInvitationButton" class="sendInvitationButton">Send Invitation</div>
                            <div id="popup_menu_support_cancelInvitationButton" class="cancelInvitationButton">Cancel</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sendInvitationContainer">
                    <div class="mailImageBg">
                        <div class="mailImage"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="textsAndButtons">
                        <div id="popup_menu_support_invitedText" class="invitedText"></div>
                        <div id="popup_menu_support_errorInviteText" class="errorInviteText"></div>
                        <div id="popup_menu_support_inviteAnotherPersonButton" class="inviteAnotherPersonButton">Invite another person</div>
                        <div id="popup_menu_support_closeInviteButton" class="closeButton">Close</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="popup_menu_support_inviteColleaguesErrorTooltip" class="yellowTooltip tooltipText" style="display: none;">
                <div id="popup_menu_support_inviteColleaguesErrorTooltipTextPlaceholder"></div>
            </div>


            <div class="popup_menu_ul">
                <div class="popup_menu_title">
                    HELP &amp; SUPPORT
                </div>
                <ul class="popup_menu_items">
                    <li class="popup_menu_separator"></li>

                    <li class="popup_menu_item"><a class="item_link" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="MenuHandler.openIntroVideo('KJOoBh5s84w'); return false;" style="position: relative">
                        Introduction Video
                        <div class="icon_intro"></div>
                    </a></li>

                    <li class="popup_menu_separator"></li>

                    <li class="popup_menu_item"><a class="item_link" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="MenuHandler.openUserGuide(); return false;">User Guide</a></li>

                    <li class="popup_menu_item"><a class="item_link" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="MenuHandler.openFaq(); return false;">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>

                    <li class="popup_menu_item"><a class="item_link" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="MenuHandler.openAbout(); return false;">About your actiTIME</a></li>
                    <li class="popup_menu_separator"></li>
                    <li class="popup_menu_item"><a class="item_link" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="MenuHandler.reportABug();">Contact actiTIME Support</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>   


<div id="requestCallPhoneContainer_support" class="requestCallPhone">
    <div class="phoneInputBlock">
        <div class="requestPhoneText">Need more info? Request a call:</div>
        <div class="inputPhoneContainer">
            <div id="countryCodePlaceholder_support" class="countryCodeSelector"></div>
            <input maxlength="32" type="text" class="inputFieldWithPlaceholder phoneInput phonePlaceHolder" id="phoneInput_support" placeholder="Phone Number">
            <div id="sendPhoneButton_support" class="sendPhoneButton">Send</div>
        </div>
        <div class="errorAnswer" style="display: none">
            The server is not responding.
            <div class="pleaseTryAgainButton">Please try again</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="phoneSendBlock" style="display: none">
        <div class="backgroundImage">
            <div class="mailImage"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="phoneWasSendBlock" style="display: none">
        <div class="thankText">Thanks, we received your request!</div>
        <div class="contactWithUserText">We will contact you as soon as possible.</div>
        <div id="closePhoneWasSendButton_support" class="closeButton">Close</div>
    </div>
</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


                                            </div>

                                            <div class="topMenuButton">
                                                <!--Tips menu button placeholder-->
                                                <div class="popup_menu_container">
                                                    <div class="popup_menu_button popup_menu_button_tips" onclick="PageOverlayTipsManager.getInstance().toggle()">
                                                        <div class="popup_menu_icon tips_icon_light_on"></div>
                                                        <div class="popup_menu_label">
                                                            Tips
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody></table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="secondLevelRow">


            <td class="secondLevelCell" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td>    


        <td class="secondLevelCell selectedColNum1  " colspan="6">


            <div class="secondLevelNavigationItem selected ">

                    <a class="item active">Enter Time-Track</a>

            </div>


            <div class="secondLevelNavigationItem  ">

                    <a href="/adbc/user/view_tt.do" class="item">View Time-Track</a>

            </div>


            <div class="secondLevelNavigationItem  ">

                    <a href="/adbc/user/lock_tt.do" class="item">Lock Time-Track</a>

            </div>


            <div class="secondLevelNavigationItem  ">

                    <a href="/adbc/administration/approve_tt.do" class="item">Approve Time-Track</a>
```

Summary:-

- Please correct me if my approach of implementing the locator is not appropriate and also how can I extract tables of a particular area without extracting the elements of the
    lower sub-tables*

  I apologize if i could not summarize all this in a few sentences.I wish stack overflow had attachments which could have made my life easier

Comment: I have no clue about Selenium, but I am wondering why you're using a `<table>` to create your menu. It's definitely NOT a `<table>`, and a menu, in most cases, is a list, and should be implemented using `<ul>`, nested such, if need be. Just a FYI.

Comment: I dont know if you have misunderstood my question.Just to clear the air this is a website that I have picked to  test my scripts.

Comment: Aha. Then you have no say in the creation of the menu :) Carry on.

Comment: If this is some random site you have picked to practice on, please post a link to the site. Posting that much unformatted HTML is not really helpful.

Comment: https://www.actitime.com/ u may need to login to find the website with these elements.I'm sorry I had no idea how to format the html with those locator that's why in the beginning I had to type all the DOM on my own it was quite painful..

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement>all_links=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class ='navTable']//tr[1]//a[contains(@class,'content')]/div[contains(@class,'label')]"));
```

Try this xpath, you can remove the first xpath search in your code. I am hoping 'reports' has the same structure as in the xpath, it is not included in the html you have posted.

Another thing - From your code this is not correct `List<WebElement>all_links=e.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'label')]"));`
To search within an element you need to prefix xpath with a dot '.', otherwise your whole document is searched instead of using the element as a context.

Comment: Excellent Thank you.I'm  somewhat flummoxed when it comes to writing xpath.It takes me ages  to write xpath. Just wanted to ask how do you guys manage to do this in seconds any pointers for me .

Comment: Google selenium webdriver locator tutorials or on youtube. There is a plethora of information. actitime is a good site to learn xpath or css locators as its html structure is kinda mixed up so more fun and pain.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need an XPath here given that HTML. You can just use a CSS selector, `"div.label"`, e.g. `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.label"));` That will exclude the `div`s inside the tables.

If you look at the two sets of `div`s, you will see that they are:

```
<div class="label" style="z-155">
<div class="pop_up_menu_label" ...>
```

so the class names on these are actually different and can be easily distinguished.

---

Here are a couple references for CSS selectors

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors

Comment: Yes I did inspect the element with that locator in chrome but unfortunately it does select another class with similar name which is a table inside this one

Comment: Can you post some more relevant HTML? Especially the new tags that are getting scraped by this CSS selector? Maybe there's a way around it.